# Unable to locate a Local Database

Tags: sql, database, connection-string

**I am getting below error when i update database:**

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

> provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local
>   Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is
>   properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is
>   enabled.

**My Connection string section**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Publicspeaking-20171215094113.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Publicspeaking-20171215094113;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

My SQL server Log In:

> **Server Name:** LAPTOP-UH0CMBJT
>   **User Name:** LAPTOP-UH0CMBJT\waqas

Comment: issue was: In Web-config file;connection String did not have the right path. I went into one of my old projects and found the right path.